# BeautifulSoup Installed but still get ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I installed BeautifulSoup successfully.  It's the latest update.  But I still get "

```
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

when running the code.
need help!!

Comment: can you provide the code?
You should use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` not `import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```